# Angular - show/hide form based on action

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm implementing a simple login/register app with `Angular 4`. What I want to achieve is to have the default view displaying the login form, and only when I click on a *Register* link I want to display the register form, that has to replace the login form.
Right now I have to click on the *Login* link to display it. I'll paste some code.

**App Module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { UserService } from './services/user/user.service';
import { User } from './services/user/user';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  providers: [UserService, User],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**App Component Template**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right">
      <nav>
        <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
        <a routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active">Register</a>
      </nav>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Login Component Template**

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" ngModel #username="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" ngModel #password="ngModel">
  </div>
  <span *ngIf="onSubmit(loginForm)">true</span>
  <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

**Register Component Template**

```
<form #registerForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(registerForm)">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Nome</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" ngModel #name="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="lastName">Cognome</label>
    <input id="lastName" name="lastName" ngModel #lastName="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" ngModel #username="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" ngModel #password="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="passwordRep">Ripeti la password</label>
    <input id="passwordRep" name="passwordRep">
  </div>
  <button>Registrati</button>
</form>
```

Is there some `Router Module` setting that I'm missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routing you need to **[redirect](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-a-redirect-route)** the user to the `login` page if you want it as default view. So try the following:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { 
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }, 
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome, glad to hear it fit your needs! Have a great day and haaappy coding! :)