# Angular4 - delete previous view when browsing to the next one

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm writing an `Angular` app that has a *login* form and a *registration* form. I want that, when I switch from one view to the other, the previous view disappears, showing only the actual view content. Right now all views are shown one under the other.
I'm sensing that I might be wrong with some `routing` setting.
Could anyone give me a hint? 
Thanks.

**App Module**

```
[...some imports...]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  providers: [UserService, User],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**App Component Template**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right">
      <login-form></login-form>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Login Component Template**

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" ngModel #username="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" ngModel #password="ngModel">
  </div>
  <button>Login</button>
  <span>{{message}}</span>
</form>
<button (click)="goToRegister()">Registrati</button>
```

**Login Component**

```
[...some imports...]
export class LoginComponent {
  private message = '';

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router
  ){}

  goToRegister(): void{
    this.router.navigate(['register']);
  }

  onSubmit(loginForm: NgForm): string {
    if (this.userService.login(
      loginForm.value.username,
      loginForm.value.password
    )) {
      this.router.navigate(['home']);
    }
    else {
      this.message = 'Login failed, please retry';
      return this.message;
    }
  }
}
```

**Register Component Template**

```
<form #registerForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(registerForm)">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Nome</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" ngModel #name="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="lastName">Cognome</label>
    <input id="lastName" name="lastName" ngModel #lastName="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" ngModel #username="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" ngModel #password="ngModel">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="passwordRep">Ripeti la password</label>
    <input id="passwordRep" name="passwordRep">
  </div>
  <button>Registrati</button>
</form>
```

**Register Component**

```
[...some imports...]
export class RegisterComponent {

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ){}

  onSubmit(registerForm: NgForm): boolean{

    var user = new User();
    user.name = registerForm.value.name;
    user.lastName = registerForm.value.lastName;
    user.username = registerForm.value.username;
    user.password = registerForm.value.password;

    return this.userService.create(user);
  }
}
```

Comment: You want your login form be displayed in all your views ?

Comment: what this question is about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276556/angular-show-hide-form-based-on-action

Comment: @ArunKumaresh it was related to this one. This one is more specific as I better understood my problem. I would have deleted the prevoius one but I couldn't, anyway I had a great hint on the other answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<login-form></login-form>` isn't needed, `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is used to switch between components/routes, please see below:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

Delete `<login-form></login-form>` from you App template and let `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` handle page transitions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right">
      <login-form></login-form> // remove this line . The router-outlet will handle all page transitions
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```